# Meteor: manually update catalog

Tags: meteor

My application is behind a corporate firewall and proxy. I am able to add new packages but somehow I cannot update the catalog. Probably because websockets are not allowed through the firewall.

Is there a method to manually get the latest catalog? The proxy variables HTTPS_PROXY and HTTP_PROXY are set of course.

```
Opening db file /pkgs/meteor/.meteor/package-metadata/v2.0.1/packages.data.db
In remote catalog refresh
lastSync =  { timestamp: 1509131556799, _id: 'lastsync' }
Unable to update package catalog (are you offline?)

If you are using Meteor behind a proxy, set HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY environment variables or see this page for more details:
https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Using-Meteor-behind-a-proxy
Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400
```

Comment: You can try to set `METEOR_OFFLINE_CATALOG=1`.

Comment: How do I update the offline catalog? Can the packages.data.db file be downloaded manually somehwere?

Comment: IIRC, it's a sqlite db built by Meteor's `catalog` tool. It should be in sync with the local package cache, so it won't really help to only get the db file. You could sync it with a Meteor installation outside the firewall, but I think that asking the IT department for an exception might be in place.

Comment: I was hoping that I could at least disable websocket for the refresh..

Answer (score 0):

You could update the catalog on your dev machine, then build it and deploy with the updated packages as a tar.gz in the restricted environment.

Otherwise just remove all packages and then add them back in if that downalods the latest version of all the packages.

Comment: That will not work. As it will only download the latest version stated in the catalog. Will try to pull it on my laptop and move the files across.

Answer (score 0):

The "solution" was

1. Meteor refresh on my laptop with normal internet connection
2. Copy the content .meteor/package-metadata/ to the internal system
3. Run Meteor update with `METEOR_OFFLINE_CATALOG=1`

Quite an annoying process. I think a `meteor refresh` should be done without Websockets or at least have the choice of disabling. `DISABLE_WEBSOCKETS=1` did not work in my case.